# How do I maintain the original increment after deleting records from my database?

Tags: sqlite3-python

I have a database created with its id on autoincrement. However after deleting records and adding a new record, the id of the new record started from the id of the last deleted record instead of the id of the last available record

My data table:

| id | name | surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | Smith |
| 2 | Jordan | Reins |
| 3 | Echo | Raymond |

```
with sqlite3.connect("names.db") as connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM names WHERE id > 1;")
```

Then later:

```
with sqlite3.connect("names.db") as connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO names (name, surname) VALUES(?, ?);", ("Bob", "Marley"))
```

I was hoping that to see:

| id | name | surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | Smith |
| 2 | Bob | Marley |

However I got:

| id | name | surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | Smith |
| 4 | Bob | Marley |

Comment: I'm sorry if my text looks horrible. I'm kind of new to this stuff :(

Comment: That's how auto-increment works; if you don't want that behavior, don't use it.

Comment: guess there's no coming out of this one :(